# iphone sdk how to change the wall paper for every 5 seconds?

Tags: iphone, ios4, wallpaper

I am having a requirement like i want to change the wallpapers in iphone like in mac change the wallpapers for every 5 seconds.Is this one possible or not.If it is possible how to achieve it.can anyone share the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the background image, and lock  screen images, is not allowed by Apple.  While it would be cool to do, an app with this functionality will be rejected by Apple during the review process.

Comment: I am having another doubt.we can create new groups in photo library in iphone .i want to take the photo library photos.How to get the photos that i want to get folder wise .

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this. your applications are in sandbox and you don't have access to this functionality nor access to system folders